# Prioritization of mod_proxy_html ProxyHTMLURLMap rules

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I am implementing a reverse proxy with the following configuration:

```
ProxyPass /home/ http://serverA.com/
ProxyPassReverse /home/ http://serverA.com/
<Location /home/>
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /rs/ http://paywall.com/ L
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /home/
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
</Location>
```

*ProxyHTMLURLMap / /home/* makes sure that all links starting with / is rewritten as proxy.com/home/. However, I want URLS that start with /rs/ to be rewritten as paywall.com/.

Unfortunately, it seems that the "ProxyHTMLURLMap / /home/" configuration always takes effect. How can I set the priority of the "ProxyHTMLURLMap /rs/ http://paywall.com/ L" configuration to a higher priority? When I comment out "ProxyHTMLURLMap / /home/", rewriting the URL to paywall.com is effective.